# How to selectByVisibleText using js executeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this js code to remove some hidden dropdown element:

```
//select account from dropdown using javascript
    val js: JavascriptExecutor = driver.asInstanceOf[JavascriptExecutor]
    js.executeScript("$('.select-upload_company_id>.center').html(" + invoice.companyNumber + ")") //visible one
    val cmd: String = "$('#company_id option[value=\"" + invoice.companyNumber + "\"]').eq(1).attr('selected','selected')" //hidden
    js.executeScript(cmd)
```

currently its selecting by value, but I want to select by visible text....how do I do that here? what do I need to change in this code?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "contains" selector for selecting option by text.

Example selector:

```
 $('#company_id option:contains(\"" + invoice.companyNumber + "\")');
```